# magento enterprise_targetrule/index model not saving

Tags: mysql, magento, model

I am executing this code:

```
$model1 = Mage::getModel('enterprise_targetrule/index')->load(5511);
var_dump($model1);
$model2 = Mage::getModel('enterprise_targetrule/index')->
    load(5511)->
    setFlag('0')->
    save();
var_dump($model2);
$model3 = Mage::getModel('enterprise_targetrule/index')->load(5511);
var_dump($model3);
die();
```

The outputs from the var_dump calls are exactly what I would expect: `$_data[flag]` is 1 for `$model1`, 0 for `$model2` and `$model3`, and `$_origData[flag]` is 1 for `$model1` and `$model2`, and 0 for $model3.

So far, it is all looking exactly right. However, when I then (immediately after running this code), execute `select * from enterprise_targetrule_index` on my database, I get this result:

```
mysql> select * from enterprise_targetrule_index;
+-----------+----------+-------------------+---------+------+
| entity_id | store_id | customer_group_id | type_id | flag |
+-----------+----------+-------------------+---------+------+
|      5511 |        7 |                 0 |       1 |    1 |
```

WHY?

Why is the flag not getting updated? The models are correct, all the fields are correct, the save and load calls all succeed and return perfect results, but the database is not updated! It's like the change I save() doesn't get written, and yet can somehow still be loaded, at least within that script. What is going on here? What is special about this model, that makes it unable to save?

Comment: Update: I turned on mysql general query log - no queries were made for this table. How can that be? I am loading it, after all...

Answer (score 0):

$model2 = Mage::getModel('enterprise_targetrule/index')->load(5511);
$model2->setFlag('0');
$model2->save();
echo $model2->getFlag();

If you use var_dump it displays the whole Object..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason for this, is the die. When sql queries are executed, they are only performed in memory - they don't get written to the database until and unless the process terminates successfully. Because I was using die(), this prevented the queries from being written.

I was thrown by this initially, because it occurs entirely in memory and not in the database. Once it is written, it does go down as a transaction, but the transaction all gets written at the same time, which is why I didn't see the rollback command in the mysql general log - it wasn't technically rolling back, but preventing even the first query from being written. Very strange, and does make testing harder, but good to keep in mind.